# How to use fetch from Sapper client

Tags: javascript, express, svelte, sapper

This is my `server.js` file

```
import { json } from 'body-parser';

import sirv from 'sirv';
// import polka from 'polka';
import compression from 'compression';
import * as sapper from '@sapper/server';
import express from 'express';

const { PORT, NODE_ENV } = process.env;
const dev = NODE_ENV === 'development';


express() // You can also use Express
    .use(
        json(),
        compression({ threshold: 0 }),
        sirv('static', { dev }),
        sapper.middleware()
    )
    .listen(PORT, err => {
        if (err) console.log('error', err);
    });
```

This is the endpoint I'm trying to reach

located in `src/routes/contact.js`

```
export async function post(req, res, next) {
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json')
    const data = req.body

    console.log(data);

    return res.end(JSON.stringify({ success: true }))
}
```

And this is the fetch

```
    fetch('/contact', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: 'Hola mundo',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
    }).then(() => {
        console.log('Form submitted');
    })
```

But network reports NOT FOUND, What I'm missing here? I thought it was a matter of polka then I switched to Express but the issue remains

PD: This is my reference Post for the structure

[fetch post is giving me undefined for the posted data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58127604/fetch-post-is-giving-me-undefined-for-the-posted-data?noredirect=1#comment102643440_58127604)

Comment: Did you try full server url (`http://your.servername.tld:port/contact`) as `fetch` parameter?

Comment: That would imply CORS, isn't it? and also I want to keep the routes relative

Comment: Yes it implies CORS, you'll have to deal with it anyway (I don't mean this current project). You can use `same-origin` or `no-cors` options for cors express middleware. Relative routes are good in this case, but you're debugging the issue. If "network reports NOT FOUND", I'd first check that endpoint in question exists and gives the right result. You can test API endpoint with `Postman`, `curl` or even `tcpdump` if you wish. By the way `Content-type` of `/contact` endpoint request set to `application/json` but its body is `text/plain`, so `json()` `body-parser` gives you `undefined` `req.body`

Comment: Did you find out? Your code _seems_ fine